# C# thread not listening for incoming messages from server

Tags: c#, multithreading

Every time a client connects to my TCP server, it creates a new thread specifically for that client (there are few clients so there's no worry about overflow of threads). However, after lots of debugging, I have found that once 2 clients join, **the first client can send about ~3 messages and then will no longer function**, however the second will keep functioning no matter how many times you send a message (and the first client will receive it). If a 3rd client joins the party, then the second client will have the same fate as the first one, will be able to send about ~3 messages, and then suddenly stop working without explanation. If someone could explain why this is happening, it would be much appreciated! Here's the code for the server (which I think is where the error is occuring):

```
s = listener.AcceptSocket();
clients.Add(s);

NewListener();

byte[] b = new byte[100];

while (running)
{
    try
    {
        int k = s.Receive(b);
        string message = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
        {
            message += Convert.ToChar(b[i]);
        }

        if (message == "exitprogram") //break loop
        {
            break;
        }

        ASCIIEncoding asen = new ASCIIEncoding();
        foreach (Socket client in clients)
        {
            client.Send(asen.GetBytes(message));
        }
    } catch
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error occured on thread " + Thread.CurrentThread.Name);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: From the code it looks like you are not using multithreading. Creating a thread is not all, you have to implement the while... part on the secondary thread

Comment: In general (I am not posting as an answer because of lack of information) in these cases you should try to debug and see where does the code hang. You'll probably find the answer out on your own

Comment: @usr-local-ΕΨΗΕΛΩΝ Why do you even bother posting if you're not going to help the OP?

Comment: Sir, I wanted to help but I don't have enough information for an answer, so I posted a comment. I would like to know what the NewListener function does. I could also handwrite for you some of the code to show what looks to me the correct pattern but I cannot easily run your sample. I am sorry if you misunderstood my earlier comment